# Blending Images in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, transparency

[image: Transparent]   [image: Colored]

I have two images named Transparent and Colored as shown above. I want to

1. Show Transparent Image First
2. As user touches the screen, reveal the colored image on finger strokes.

This is my drawRect code.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage *colorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"];
    UIImage *bwImage    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];    
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context1, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);

    // Draw the finger Strokes
    for (UIBezierPath *path in [touchPaths allValues]) {
    [path stroke];

    }

CGContextDrawImage(context1, rect, colorImage.CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context1, rect, bwImage.CGImage);    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}

The code above just creates a blank screen. What am I doing wrong here ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Working in a single view's `drawRect` method means that every time the user draws something, you will need to draw two images and a bezier path.  This will be quite inefficient.  You need a way to store the images and the drawing area in separate places.

CALayer is good for this sort of problem.  You can store the images in layers, and have the user's drawing mask one of the layers.  Start with the [CALayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), including the examples.

For truly smooth drawing, you OpenGL - although it takes a lot more work to get right.  See Apple's [GLPaint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328) example.

---

As for why this code isn't working, it does draw the two images.  However, the second image drawn will be `transparentImage`.  Your attachments imply that this is opaque gray.  This will leave your view filled with gray, appearing to do nothing.  If you're sure it is not drawing even that much, check the following:

1. Are you constructing a view of this class somewhere - either in Interface Builder or in code?
2. Are you adding this view within the views of a view controller that you know is being displayed?
3. Are you giving this view a size?  Newly created views can have width and height zero, making them effectively invisible.
4. Are your image loading routines returning anything?

Some of these can be tested with logging.  For example, to check if the images properly loaded:

```
UIImage *colorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"];
UIImage *bwImage    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];    

// Check if the images loaded.
NSLog(@"colorImage = %@", colorImage);
if (!colorImage)
    NSLog(@"colorImage did not load, nothing to draw");

NSLog(@"bwImage = %@", bwImage);
if (!bwImage)
    NSLog(@"bwImage did not load, nothing to draw");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`, but you never called `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(...)`, so it's probably removing the default drawing context (or something equally crazy). That line shouldn't be there; those functions are used for creating your own `UIImage`, which you don't need to do here.

Comment: I am calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext. I was under impression that drawRect already creates a context to draw into. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, when `drawRect` is called, a context has been created for you, and that context is closed after `drawRect` returns.  It is not an image context, and you don't need to close it.  You don't need anything to balance `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.  It just returns the current state.  It doesn't construct anything new, so there is nothing to be disposed of.